# rails query serializable object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

How do I query the database to find objects that contain one or more attributes that are stored as serializable?

For example, I have a concert which occurs only in certain cities. I want to make a Concert object with a column called cities and store an array of cities.

If I want to query my database to find all concerts that occur in 1 city (or all concerts that occur in an array of n cities), how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this isn't to store it in a serialized column, but a separate table called Cities. Then you can do this:

```
City.find_by_name('Cityname').concerts
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to query would be to use SQL's LIKE condition. This would work for boolean conditions in serialized tables.

For example to find those Users with the 'notification' option on,

```
users=User.arel_table
User.where(users[:options].matches("%notification: true%"))
```

As for other type of variables this would not be as feasible.